# Available Kernel Updates

Tags: kernel, updates, 18.04, ubuntu-mate, vulnerability

I've always been kinda picky and skeptical about kernel updates from one version to another(like 4.15.0.x to 4.15.0.y). I have the following updates available in my software updater...

[image]

I usually don't apply these type of updates, but I've recently heard that a **spectre variant 4 vulnerability** has been found in the Linux kernel...

So should I apply these updates? Vulnerabilities aside, are these updates really necessary? My only concern is that something might get broken or stop working...

Comment: You seem to be asking "can I trust these updates?"  A few minutes at http://security.ubuntu.com will answer you.

Comment: @user535733 It's not about trust at all! I'm only interested to know how important are these updates- my present kernel is doing fine and such an upgrade might break something.

Comment: You can always revert back to the previous version if the updated kernel does not work, via GRUB in the advanced boot options.

Comment: It seems to me you are asking an opinion. Two considerations : 1. kernel updates are an important part of security updates and 2. The spectre vulnerabilities are going to be a long process to try to resolve and there my not be a software solution, ie you may need to upgrade your cpu.